# MySQL: additional id column vs performance

Tags: mysql, performance, unique-key

Table1 has 3 columns: id (autoincrement), citynumber (unique), description (varchar(1000)).
Column id is never used in queries. It's just used for my convenience (to see how the table grows, it's easier to refer to the id, than to the citynumber, although id is never used when make sql queries).

Would you highly recommend to remove id column to increase performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing id column will not increase the performance or, at least, not in a sensible way. You can only save same disk. Besides, the benefits that a PK can give you are usually much more better than saving space.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is up for debate, and generally i believe it best practice to keep indexes on tables, even if they are look tables.  just my opinion having worked with legacy code and database tables that don't have indexes in them, which need them later.  yes, this is a minor update statement, but the database still needs to reindex everything accordingly, which could affect performance during this update.

just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

No, ID columns are almost always there.  If you were ever to add more tables and wanted to join them, the ID column will come in handy.  It should not effect performance at all, and only minor space consumption difference.

Answer (score 0):

performance will depend on your queries.  if citynumber is indeed unique (is that a natural key?) then putting an index on that column will help greatly if that's what you're joining or filtering on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only store real (non-ficticious) cities in your database, you can easily store all of the world's cities without having to worry about performance at all - the data set is to tiny.

Answer (score 0):

In InnoDB PK works faster than Unique index, because PK points to data, and Unique points to PK and only after that - to data.

So, remove id, and make citynumber a primary key.

Stil, it's not going to give you much performance improvment.

Comment: ceding your point on 'unique' constraints vs PKs, i see no reason to remove the 'id' column.  surrogate key peers to the natual keys are useful.  even if the where clause fiters against the citynumber column, the joins could still be against surrogate PK

Comment: Why do you use joins against surogate PK? As far, as I understand from the post, datatype of id and citynumber may be the same.

Comment: could be.  i had asked in my answer if city-number was the natural key, but got no response.  as for why to join on the surrogate, i'd answer that that's what they're there for.  by definition they're there only for db purposes and should have no external meaning.